# Searching fore a specifiic function at the core! (Custom Option Attachment)

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, file-upload

I'm searching for a specific function at the Mage Core but i cannot find it!
We're selling temporary tattoos online and customer are able to upload their image (Custom Option File Attachment).

It would be awesome, if the uploaded image would be displayd as thumbnail in the shopping cart.

I got an idea how i can solve my problem, but i cannot find this one function I need!

Here is the place where the thumbnail should be displayed:

[image: Here is the place where the thumbnail should be displayed.]

Here is the code i need to change.[image]

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the return function at **line 525** in the magento 1.9.2.1 file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php
```

to the following:

```
return sprintf('<img src="%s" alt="%s" class="cartCustomerImage" /><a class="cartCustomerImageDesc" href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a> %s',
    $this->_getOptionDownloadUrl($urlRoute, $urlParams),
    Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($title),
    $this->_getOptionDownloadUrl($urlRoute, $urlParams),
    Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($title),
    $sizes
);
```

Comment: Thx for your help dude :) ! You saved me a lot of time :) !

Comment: editing core !!! big mistake.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy I know that editing the core is not the best way to solve my problem ... If you have a better idea, tell me !